# Portable Batch System

Tags: bash, shared-library

I am working in a server (I am not the admin) where I must run jobs in `.pbs` format so I can disconnect my computer while a job is running.

The problem is that I cannot run in .pbs format the same commands I'm able to run in .sh format, it says:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libftgl.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This library is located in `/usr/lib264`.

I tried to export this library but I may have done it wrong.

How to do it exactly?

[image: .sh and .pbs files]

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `ld` (the GNU linker) can't find the library, because the library isn't either in an `ld` trusted path nor the library's path has been made available to `ld` by other means.

So you should make the library's path available to `ld`.

Since you don't have administration privileges, you'll have to override your local `ld` settings, which can be done by adding the path to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable:

```
printf "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\"$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib264\n\"" >>~/.bashrc
```

And by sourcing `~/.bashrc` to apply the changes to the running shell:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

The "right" way to make the libraries contained in `/usr/lib264` available system-wide would be to add a `.conf` file containing the library's path in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` and to update the `ld` cache.

This requires administration privileges, so it does not apply to your case; however I'm leaving this for other people stumbling across this answer.

First, one should add a `.conf` file containing the library's path in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`:

```
printf "/usr/lib264\n" | sudo tee -a /etc/ld.so.conf.d/other_libraries.conf
```

Then, one should run `ldconfig` to update the `ld` cache:

```
ldconfig
```

After that, the library's path should be available to `ld` system-wide.

Comment: "i am not the admin" .. so he'll have to use the wrong way, which was `LD_PRELOAD_PATH`, iirc.

Comment: Thanks, so i must add this to the pbs file? it didn't work!

          printf "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\"$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib64\n\"" >>~/.bashrc  
    . ~/.bashrc  

This is the library path


    whereis libftgl.so.2
    libftgl.so: /usr/lib64/libftgl.so.2 /usr/lib64/libftgl.so

Comment: @MHG No, you just run the two commands in a whatever (Bash) shell: `printf "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\"$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib264\n\"" >>~/.bashrc` (this adds a line to `~/.bashrc`) and then `. ~/.bashrc` to apply the changes. After that, PBS scripts should work.

Comment: it didn't work.

i created a script .sh with command 

and make it executable , then run it. is that the right way? excuse me i am not used to unix system

Comment: @MHG You need to *run* (execute) the two commands in a terminal *once*, in the same way you'd run `echo foo`, `sudo apt-get install bar` etc. To check that the command succeded, *run* (in the same way) `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`; if the output of the latter contains `/usr/lib264` at the end, the command succeded. At this point, try running a PBS script.

Comment: Apparently i have another problem, i will gonna contact the server admin, thanks alot

Comment: @MHG What do you mean with "I have another problem"? This wasn't the problem in first place?

Comment: @kos No this was the problem but ur solution didn't work unfortunately, when i will contact the admin i may understand more why this is happening.
Thank u very much for helping :)

Comment: @MHG No problem. Let me know if you have updates on this, maybe we can try something else.